# Why is Internet Explorer 9 not displaying CSS for first 50 elements?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I have an online test which includes 24 questions, each with 4 possible answers. I have set up the CSS so that these answers are radio buttons with labels and a hover effect.

Here's a picture of how it looks in Chrome, Firefox, IE 10, Opera, iPad, Android - everything except IE 9:

[image: Normal test CSS behaviour]

Yet in IE 9 it looks like this for question 1:

[image: test broken in IE 9]

By the time the user gets to question 13 it looks like this, where the CSS starts working on the 51st element that the styling is applied to:

[image: 51st element CSS starts working]

And then every question after that looks correct.

[image: CSS working in IE 9 from that point onwards]

Here's a link to the test where you can see the code embedded in an iframe:

http://improvedemployees.com/softskills/soft-skills-test/

Here's a link to the raw test code (it behaves the same):

http://api.improvedemployees.com/soft-skills/softskills-test2.aspx?v=4&companyid=10812&testid=1&campaign=

To see this problem in action, enter a couple of characters for the name it asks and click next a couple of times to get to question 1.

Why is Internet Explorer 9 refusing to display the CSS for the first 50 elements? Note: there are fewer than 200 elements on this test so I don't believe there should be any limit problem.

Comment: Because one of your included JS files applies `border: transparent` to your elements if it detects IE<10. At least that's what I get from the inspector.

Comment: JS Errors popping up for me.

Comment: really? wow - I'll go check that - but then why does it only apply transparent to the first 50 in that case and where has the hover/selected effect gone?

Comment: Same of all the above. In adittion, I have seen in IE8 the browser start aplying correct styles at page 6.

Comment: Just make sure that you're in proper IE9 also! Hit F12 and make sure you're not in IE9 mode with quirks standards! That nonsense happens to me all the time.

Comment: futher to my answer i have notice that some inline css is overriding the css so kindly check that too. if using developer tool i disable the inline css it works fine in IE9

Comment: In my development environment it actually works, although the difference seems to be I'm getting SCRIPT87: Invalid Argument errors in production but not locally.

Comment: regarding the transparent borders: This is to prevent the little dotted lines appearing around the checkbox in firefox when the radio box is selected - it's only being applied to input[type="radio"]:checked

Comment: Noteably, I get 20 script87 errors

Comment: @ShafqatMasood - there is no inline CSS. It's all based on classes. I'm not sure where you're seeing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was to do with the following command being applied to the .radiolabel class:

```
behavior: url(/css/border-radius.htc);
```

I'd added that to make the rounded border effect backwards compatible.

Removing that line, now all the effects are there as expected.

This also explains why it was working in my development environment but not my production environment - it was referring to /css/border-radius.htc whereas to pick up the file in my dev environment I should have been using a relative path or /web/css/...

Thanks to @Zeta for pointing out about the transparency effect. Took me a while to find this, but the code in that .htc file was the culprit. I'd appreciate knowing what tool you used to discover that?

This has also removed the SCRIPT87 errors - they were being caused by some dodgy code inside the .htc file too.

You can see it working finally here:

http://api.improvedemployees.com/soft-skills/softskills-test2.aspx?v=4&companyid=10812&testid=1&campaign=

Thanks to all who helped.

[image: IE Working!]

Answer (score -2):

For me its working fine in IE 10

[image: my IE 10 works fine]

i press f12 and set the Browser Mode to IE 9

then it was not working and as i turn off the compatibility by selecting Browser Mode = E10 and its works fine as shown in figure.

so check at your end make css compatible with IE9 or change your JS

i have observed that some inline css is overriding the css so kindly check that too

Comment: You need to set `document mode` not `browser mode`

Comment: If you go to Question 13, it starts working again as described above. That doesn't answer why and how to solve it - my CSS IS compatible with IE9 (as far as I can tell) - it just doesn't get applied to the first 50 elements.